# "You can pick up the keys on/at the reception desk"

Tags: prepositions

> You can pick up the keys **(on/at)** the reception desk.

The website where I'm learning English says it's *at*. But is it OK to use *on* here?

Comment: Not unless someone accidentally left the keys lying on the desk. "You can pick up the keys at the reception desk" means a hotel employee will hand you the keys to your room once you have identified yourself by name and/or room number.

Comment: The wording "You can pick up the keys at the reception desk" is an idiomatically correct phrase; I suspect that it is a shortened form of something like "You can pick up the keys by inquiring at the reception desk." Similarly "You can pick up the keys from the reception desk" would be acceptable as a shortened form of "You can pick up the keys from the person at the reception desk. But as Mark Hubbard notes, "You can pick up the keys on the reception desk" would only work as a shortened form of an instruction such as "You can pick up the keys that you will find lying on the reception desk."

Answer (score 2):

The prepositions **at** and **on** give different meanings.

The use of **at** means that you will get the keys from an employee who is working the reception desk.  The use of **at** signifies a location which is different than on.

The use of **on** means the keys are physically located *on a desk*, in the same way a pen, hotel brochure, or plant may be.

Neither one is more correct.  The website gives **at** as the correct answer because in the context of that learning material, **at** is the correct answer.  I'm guessing but the material might be about travel English.

More uses of **at** to help you understand the particular usage the book is teaching:

*You can get aspirin at the drugstore.*

*You can pick up your car at the valet station.*

*They sell keys at the hardware store.*

*You can get a map of the town at the front desk.*